# MySQL (and WordPress): select rows containing the highest value in one column and order by another

Tags: mysql, wordpress

This was not so hard before moving my data to WordPress but I'm not certain how to get the same results: a certain number of posts belongs together (like an issue of a magazine) with articles, ordered manually. I want to get all the articles from the latest issue and order them according to another field.

With my old tables I could do

```
select title, issue, num
from magazine
where issue = (
select max(issue)
from magazine
)
order by num
```

With WordPress, the data is split into two tables, one for posts (articles) and another for the metadata.

I can get all the articles of the latest issue with the following query:

```
select post_title, post_date from wp_posts 
where ID in (select post_id 
             from wp_postmeta 
             where meta_key = 'myissue' and meta_value = (select max(meta_value + 0) 
                                                          from wp_postmeta 
                                                          where meta_key = 'myissue'));
```

The question is: how do I order the result by another custom field?

Comment: What is the field you want to order by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
select post_title, post_date, meta_value
    from wp_posts, wp_postmeta
    where ID in (
        select post_id
            from wp_postmeta
                where meta_key = 'myissue'
                and meta_value = (
                    select max(meta_value + 0)
                        from wp_postmeta
                            where meta_key = 'myissue'
                )
       )
    and ID = post_id
    and meta_key = 'myorder'
    order by meta_value + 0;
```

Comment: The above is limited only to the latest issue (the max of meta_key 'myissue'), how do I order the entire database on the two meta_keys? Normally, I would use `order by myissue, myorder`, how do I do it here?

Comment: `select t3.post_title, i, o
        from (
            select meta_value as i, post_id
                from $wpdb->postmeta
                    where meta_key = 'myissue'
            ) as t1,
            (
            select meta_value as o, post_id
                from $wpdb->postmeta
                    where meta_key = 'myorder'
            ) as t2,
            $wpdb->posts as t3
                where t1.post_id = t2.post_id
                and t2.post_id = ID
                    order by i + 0 desc,
                    o + 0
        limit 20;`

Comment: I didn't think I could do it. I guess, however, that the above code is only a quick hack and could be optimized by experts.

Answer (score 1):

If your query does not return many results the easiest way is to use temporary table.
The query would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
select post_title, post_date from wp_posts 
where ID in (select post_id 
             from wp_postmeta 
             where meta_key = 'myissue' and meta_value = (select max(meta_value + 0) 
                                                          from wp_postmeta 
                                                          where meta_key = 'myissue'))
) tmptbl ORDER BY post_date DESC;
```